# Irreducible polynomial with degree 2 over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $\deg f=2$. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(x)=(x-a)^2 +b^2$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \neq 0$.

I don't know how to do the first part of this exercise and I need some help.

For the way back I did:

If $f(x)=(x-a)^2 +b^2$, to get $f(x)=0$, We need $a=0$ and $b=0$. But, by hypothesis, $b \neq 0$. So $f(x)$ doesn't have roots in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Is this part right?

Comment: I think you forget to say that $f(x)$ is monic.

Comment: I guess they assume monic. In that case, any $x^2 + cx + d$ can be written as $(x+ \frac{c}{2})^2  + ( d - \frac{c^2}{4} )  $

Comment: Right. Actually, the exercise does not mention about monic. But I will try it, thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $f(x)$ is irreducible, it has two conjugate roots $\zeta,\bar\zeta$, so it factors over $\bf C$ as
\begin{align}
f(x)&=(x-\zeta)(x-\bar\zeta)=x^2-(\zeta+\bar\zeta)x+\zeta\bar\zeta \\
&=x^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\zeta)x+|\zeta|^2=\bigl(x-\operatorname{Re}(\zeta)\bigr)^2-\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(\zeta)\bigr)^2+|\zeta|^2 \\
&=\cdots
\end{align}